# apt-get upgrade fails: "guvcview : Depends: libguvcview-2.0-0 but it is not installed"

Tags: apt, upgrade

EDIT: My question is a duplicate but my answer here is a bit different than the answer in the linked duplicate above.

I cannot install, remove, or upgrade anything using APT because of this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 guvcview : Depends: libguvcview-2.0-0 but it is not installed
            Recommends: uvcdynctrl but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I'm certain I can find and fix this error. I'm more interested in knowing why the entirety of apt is broken because of one program having a problem.

Edit: I can't `apt-get dist-upgrade` either:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 guvcview : Depends: libguvcview-2.0-0 but it is not installed
            Recommends: uvcdynctrl but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

`apt-get -f install` is met with this error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../libguvcview-2.0-0_2.0.5+ubuntu2~ppa1+1418-0ubuntu1~201702081552~ubuntu16.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libguvcview-2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.5+ubuntu2~ppa1+1418-0ubuntu1~201702081552~ubuntu16.10.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libguvcview-2.0-0_2.0.5+ubuntu2~ppa1+1418-0ubuntu1~201702081552~ubuntu16.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgviewaudio-2.0.so.2.0.0', which is also in package libguvcview-2.0-2:amd64 2.0.4+debian-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libguvcview-2.0-0_2.0.5+ubuntu2~ppa1+1418-0ubuntu1~201702081552~ubuntu16.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It should be noted that the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgviewaudio-2.0.so.2.0.0` does not exist on my system.

I can't do anything with APT because of this. I can't even remove an unrelated program. `abiword` is a text editor.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove abiword
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 guvcview : Depends: libguvcview-2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: uvcdynctrl but it is not going to be installed
 lubuntu-desktop : Depends: abiword but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

OS: Lubuntu desktop (Ubuntu 16.10)

Comment: Possibly relevant: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/301745)

Comment: See my post (edited) for the output of the commands suggested in that answer. The steps taken to answer that question did not resolve my issue. Also, there is no checkbox for either of the `guvcview` programs in the Software & Updates GUI.

Comment: Did you run `ppa-purge` on the PPA or repository at the origin of `libguvcview-2.0-0=2.0.5+ubuntu2~ppa1+1418-0ubuntu1~201702081552~ubuntu16.10.1:amd64` like the accepted answer to the linked question suggests? You can find out the repository with `apt-cache policy libguvcview-2.0-0`. If you did, what exactly happened?

Comment: [16.10 is unsupported](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17101/eol-notice-yakkety-yak-16-10-reached-end-of-life-on-july-20-2017) and questions specific to it are therefore off-topic (I personally consider questions about package management via repository to be version-specific). More importantly, it is unsafe to use an EoL operating system (no security updates) and you are likely to encounter many unresolvable package management issues. Please do upgrade your system as soon as possible!

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer here:

[apt-get commands are failing with libpython3.3 unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539085/apt-get-commands-are-failing-with-libpython3-3-unmet-dependencies/539105#539105)

Apparently I had two conflicting versions of `guvcview` installed.

```
apt list --installed | grep guvc
guvcview/yakkety,now 2.0.5+ubuntu2~ppa1+1418-0ubuntu1~201702081552~ubuntu16.10.1 amd64 [installed]
libguvcview-2.0-2/yakkety,now 2.0.4+debian-1 amd64 [installed]
```

As per the answer above, I used `dkpg -r --force-depends` to remove them:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends guvcview
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends libguvcview-2.0-2
```

At that point I tried to `apt-get upgrade` again as normal:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lubuntu-desktop : Depends: guvcview but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Aha! This time I got an expected error message. `guvcview` is a package that `lubuntu-desktop` depends on: that means if I reinstall it after it's removed, everything should be back to normal, right?

After running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Everything works now. `guvcview` is working again too, which is nice, because I broke it while debugging this error.

[image: guvcview welcome back]